# How to exclude posts that are categorized as "Tutorials" from RSS feed?

Tags: php, wordpress

What I am doing is parsing RSS feed of a WordPress blog and getting information as `title`, `link`, `description`, and `pubDate` from the XML file.

```
<?php 
$html = "";
$url = "http://www.ajneffects.com/blog/feed/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
    $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
    $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
    $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;

    $html .= "<a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3></a>";
    $html .= "$description";
    // $html .= "$pubDate";
}
echo $html;
```

Sorry for the bad markup, but that's it.

The thing is, I don't want to post tagged as "Tutorials" to show in the rendered HMTL file. I'm not sure how to get it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try url like : `http://www.ajneffects.com/blog/feed/?cat=-5` 
Here 5 is your "tutorials" category id

for more see: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Comment: Never ever thought `cat=-5` thing existed! :D